# Sample android app demonstrating telephony api?

Tags: android

Is there any sample application which demonstrates the capabilities of Telephony API of android? I am interested in getting the call notifications / caller number etc(I understand its doable with PhoneStateListener). Also, Is it possible for 3rd party application to change the incoming call window / outgoing call window (basically to give the user an extra button to search the incoming number from a REST service) ?

Any useful links  or sample application would be very much helpful. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) tells your app about phone activity.  Here's some sample code from one of my apps that pauses music when the phone is active:

```
/**
 * Helper class to pause music while a phone call is in progress.
 * 
 * The Android emulator can simulate an outgoing call by clicking
 * the phone button and dialing normally.  Simulate an incoming call
 * by starting the emulator, "telnet localhost 5554" then enter 
 * "gsm call 5551234" into the telnet session.  
 */
private class MusicServicePhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean mResumeAfterCall = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incoming_number) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.i(tag, "phone active, suspending music service");
            mResumeAfterCall = mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.i(tag, "phone inactive, resuming music service");
            if (mResumeAfterCall) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Create and start the listener in onCreate via:

```
    mPhoneListener = new MusicServicePhoneStateListener();
    ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Stop the listener in onDestroy with:

```
    ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(mPhoneListener, 0);
```

As for modifying the incoming call dialog the [best suggestion I've found](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/527a945dd9500449) is to use a short delay followed by a custom toast message (delay so that your toast appears "above" the incoming call dialog).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is really helpful. However, your music app application gets started by the user with onCreate and you can register for updates. But if I wanted to write a phone manager type application for listening to each and every phone event and present some UI to the user, Do I have to write a service? The user will not start the app and it will be activated by default.  I am looking into some BroadcastListener but a little confused about the lifecycle.

Comment: "Broadcast receivers do not display a user interface. However, they may start an activity in response to the information they receive, or they may use the NotificationManager to alert the user. Notifications can get the user's attention in various ways — flashing the backlight, vibrating the device, playing a sound, and so on. They typically place a persistent icon in the status bar, which users can open to get the message."---------this gives the answer to my comment. Sorry for the ignorant comment with my lack of broadcastreceiver knowledge